# Posting an image with parameters - AFNetworking 3.1 and objective c (Xcode 8)

Tags: objective-c, image-upload, afnetworking-3, xcode8

I am looking for some leads to my problem.
I have practically looked through all links related to posting/uploading an image to a server, but nothing seems to make my code work.

I have posted 2 options... in different ways... the commented code indicates that... my request goes blank to the server.

I have tried using different options - appendPartWithFormData, appendPartWithFileData.

OPTION 1

NSError* error;

```
    // Create paths to output images
    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *imagePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pngPath];

    NSData *jsonInputData     = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[requestParameter valueForKey:@"Param"] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonInputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"converted JOSN Data %@",jsonInputString);

    NSDictionary* params = @{@"request": jsonInputString };

    [manager POST:[requestParameter valueForKey:@"methodName"] parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
     {
         //[formData appendPartWithFormData:self.imageData name:@"profilepic" ];

        //[formData appendPartWithFileData:self.imageData name:@"profilepic" fileName:@"profilepic.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonInputData name:@"request"];
         [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pngPath]
                                    name:@"File"
                                   error:nil];
     }  progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        [self requestSuccessed:responseObject];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self requestFailed:error];
    }];
```

---

OPTION 2

```
    NSError* error;

    NSData *jsonInputData     = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[requestParameter valueForKey:@"Param"] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonInputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* params = @{@"request": jsonInputString };

    AFURLSessionManager *manager1 = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“XXXXXXX”] parameters:nil error:nil];


    req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
  //  [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
   // [req setHTTPBody:[jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"pic.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:self.imageData];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [req addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"request\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:jsonInputString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [req setHTTPBody:body];

    [[manager1 dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);

            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                //blah blah
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
        }
    }] resume];
```

Comment: I think you will need some form of REST api on the server side (PHP, Perl, Node.js, etc) to listen to the post call, and actually save the file. Eventually using with some form of credentialing.

Comment: Thanks Alex..The server is implemented in Java and when I post the same request from Postmanplugin.. with a png file attached.. in formdata - the request goes fine and I get a successful response.

Comment: Did you find any solution of that. I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hopefully it will solve your problem

```
      // your parametes here
    userInfoDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [userInfoDict setValue:@"image" forKey:@"iamge"];

    // if image is too large than the timeout intervel
 //   [_request setTimeoutInterval:1000];

    _request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"api url" parameters:userInfoDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                {
                 //convert imahe into data
                    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

                    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"api paramets name in which you want to post image" fileName:@"myImage.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

                } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    _uploadTask = [manager
                   uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:_request
                   progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)

                   {
                       // This is not called back on the main queue.
                       // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            //Update the progress view
                           [_playerProgress setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];

                           NSLog(@"\n uploading image vlaues %f\n",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

                           // for uploading video in background
                          manager.attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions=YES;

                       });
                   }

                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                       if (error) {
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

                          // [_playerProgress setHidden:YES];

                       } else
                       { 
                           NSLog(@"%@ ", response);

                           // after upload comnlete disablle background uploading

                           manager.attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions=NO;

                           NSLog(@"\n\n REsponse Form Server %@\n\n",responseObject);
                           //[responseObject valueForKey:@"error"];
                                                          //remove temp file
                           NSError *error;

                       }
                   }

                   ];

    [_uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks Nouman... tried your solution but did not help... Request goes as blank

Comment: @Vijaya i updated the code this is also working for me , if you have a time you can try this.

Comment: Thanks once again Nouman...  changing from jpeg to png , I tried earlier as well, I still went ahead with your code to make sure.. i may have missed something else.. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me. You need to make sure your RESTful script pick up the correct file handle. I don't know Java, but in PHP I would do it as: `$image = $_FILES["imagename"]["name"];`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSLog(@"Saving image file");

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) name:@"imagename" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    // This is not called back on the main queue.
    // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"JSON uploadProgress.fractionCompleted: %f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
    });
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    } else {
        NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", responseString);
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks Alex... this didn't work for me either... I don't have much idea on the server, but from the android app - byte array is being sent for the image and the server picks it up fine...